# como enviar uma especie de formulario sem botao?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

bom gostaria de saber como envio uma requisição para o banco de dados. na realidade não uma requisição e sim uma inserção para quando eu clicar no `radio button` ele inserir o valor do `radio button` no banco como faco isso?

Comment: o que você ja tentou fazer ? poste o código que você ja tentou fazer

Comment: nao tentei fazer ainda quero saber como que faz pra mim comecar a tentar o que eu devo fazer para isso acontecer isso que eu quero saber assim que eu souber isso comecarei a fazer

Comment: Escute o evento de clique no radio button. Quando o usuário clicar, programe o envio de um formulário ou faça a requisição por AJAX.

Comment: tipo eu tenho a pagina de insercao ja no banco ai e so eu programar uma funcao anonima no radio button? chamando esta pagina que ele vai inserir?

Comment: Veja esse código no [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126501/submit-form-on-radio-button-click-submit-form-and-perform-other-actions-on-rad) para você ter uma noção.

Comment: obrigado galera tentarei fazer aqui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - defina por exemplo um ID ao seu formulário

2 - Use javascript

```
$(".classeDoRadio").click(function(){
   $("#idDoForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: cara mas tipo eu tenho a pagina que vai fazer a inserção no  banco dos value do `radio button` eu dando só submit não iria mudar nada como posso fazer para esse submit chamar a pagina de inserção e gravar no banco? se eu colocar action no form ele vai ocorrer tudo bem? ou nao?